# Bootstrap Dropdown in Navbar doesn't show dropdown when clicked

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a Navbar for my light control/camera monitoring system. However, for my camera dropdown whenever I go to select a specific camera, it doesn't show anything.

This is running on a Win 10 machine with the latest Django and bootstrap for development. I've tried added jQuery and updating my bootstrap files.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Light Control</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Light Control</a>
      {% if isLogged %}
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/control">Light Control<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Cameras
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/camera/office">Office</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/camera/office">ec</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>

            <a href="/logout/" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Log Out</a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </nav>
    </body>
</html>

I tried to click on the button, but nothing actually shows up once I click on it.
```

Comment: You also need to include the `bootstrap.js` file.

Comment: @xyres I just tried adding the bootstrap.js file in the head with `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` but it still does the same behavior.

Comment: If you're loading Bootstrap **after** jQuery, it should work. If it doesn't, open Dev tools in your browser (`Ctrl+Shift+I`) and select `Console` tab. Then see what error message is there.

Comment: Also, I can tell by looking at your code that it is for Bootstrap **4**. But you're including Bootstrap 3. You need to include version 4, not 3.

Comment: @xyres that did the trick. I forgot I was using bootstrap 4, thank you!